# Magento empty files

Tags: magento-1.9, image, permissions, file-permissions

I met rather unusual problem setting up [magento-1.9](/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) (Community) on VPN server.

***All files that write by Magento system are empty.*** It is including `session files` at `var/session` (currently I find way around by storing session to database), and catalog product cache images at `media/catalog/product/cache` etc.

All image files in `catalog/product` (that created when products were created) are exist, and non-empty. But cache re-sized images are all empty.

Permissions on all media and var folders have `777` permissions. Can you help me to diagnose and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you ran out of space on your harddisk.

If you have SSH access try `df -h`, else try to create a new file and write some content to that file with an FTP client like Filezilla to see if you get any errors

Comment: No, there more than 10G of empty space, and I can create (or copy) files so it is not the case.

Comment: Is the owner and the file permissions correct of the empty files?

Comment: yes. The files permissions 664, owner is www-data
All is seems correct, but files are empty

Comment: All image files in catalog/product (that created when products were created) are exist, and non-empty. But cache re-sized images are all empty.